# PHP variable for all users on server

Tags: php

It is possible to define variable in PHP and call it for all users connected on server?

I need `variable`, or `object` for store informations in RAM of the server without using database or server file system.

Save the data to the variable in one computer, and call them back in another connected computer.

What is the best practice, is it possible?

Comment: You want to use shared memory?  Why can't you use a database like Redis?  You have placed some interesting restrictions on this problem.  What do you plan to do when you want to scale to more than one server?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Memcached or Redis could be possible solutions.

Comment: I would store this info in a DB and update every time interval or on the trigger of an event.

Comment: I want to avoid database od file system during a huge number of changes per second. I hope it is possible naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly - yes, it is possible.

In order to do that you need to have access to RAM which I haven't seen in PHP done directly, not sure if is possible or not, you can research this yourself.

What you can do is, however, since PHP uses memory to run, you can take advantage of that and create a php script that will run forever and act as a server, that is going to use it's ability to write and read memory and is going to be an amazingly simple job since PHP handles that for you automatically and you would not have to bother with addresses and stuff ( describing a simple variable declaration ). In order to access this running script you will need to examine how sockets work and how to establish a server-client connection. That is very well explained in [this](http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/) article.

However, I do not mean to be rude, but by the way you form your question I can make an assumption that this *may* be too much for you, so I guess what you can do is use MemcacheD or any other in-memory caching mechanism that is already built by people better at coding than me and you. There is plenty of information out there, just search for in-memory caching mechanisms.

Good luck!